# How to trigger an ajax event listener on click of p:graphicImage?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, graphicimage

I want to do some processing when the user click on the p:graphicsImage inside a ui:repeat
How do i do it.

```
<ui:repeat id="repeat" value="#{getData.image}" var="imageLst" varStatus="loop">
   <h:panelGroup>
      <p:graphicImage id="gi1" value="#{imageStreamer.image}" alt="image not available" >
          <f:param name="id" value="#{imageLst.imageID}" />
          <p:ajax id="aj2" event="click" listener="#{getData.searchID}" immediate="true" update=":form:tabView:check :form:growl"/>
      </p:graphicImage>
   </h:panelGroup>
</ui:repeat>
```

In the above code if i place the ajax part doesn't get triggered.
How do i monitor a Click on the 'p:graphicImage'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `<p:graphicImage>` doesn't support any ajax events.

Just wrap it in a `<h:commandLink>` (or the `p:` one).

```
<h:commandLink>
    <p:graphicImage id="gi1" value="#{imageStreamer.image}" alt="image not available" >
        <f:param name="id" value="#{imageLst.imageID}" />
    </p:graphicImage>
    <p:ajax id="aj2" listener="#{getData.searchID}" update=":form:tabView:check :form:growl"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: I tried the above suggestion but once i click the image, the image disappears.

Comment: That's a different problem. Is the listener method now invoked or not?

Comment: Yes, the listener method gets invoked, but why does the image disappears. Actually all the images inside the ui:repeat disappers.

Comment: As said, that's a different problem. You need to either improve `<p:ajax update>` so that it doesn't update it, or to fix `#{getData.image}` so that it doesn't change on every request.

Comment: Ok thanks, i will try to fix one of them, need to figure out where the issue is.

Comment: Quite Confusing that the Primefaces Showcase says: "p:ajax enables ajax behavior on any JSF component."

Comment: @Sonic: take it as marketing phrase. Technically, it's only possible if the component's renderer is capable of recognizing and decoding it.